# Error while accessing column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I uploaded a dataset to jupyter notebook and did analysis using pandas,
suddenly im not able to access several columns from my dataset
im getting the error

```
"['DATE OF OCCURRENCE'] not in index"
```

I checked for whitespace error but even with columns without whitespace im still getting the error

i tried to run

```
df1 = df[['ARREST','DATE OF OCCURRENCE']]
```

got the above mentioned error 
same for 'primary description' and other columns with space but it also happened with 'IUCR' column so maybe error isnt due to white space
all columns are object class
Plzz help

Comment: please post an output of `print(df.columns.tolist())`

Comment: Check for the variable name of the dataframe once. You might have misspelled the variable name.

Comment: @MaxU   ['DATE  OF OCCURRENCE', 'CASE#', 'BLOCK', ' IUCR', ' PRIMARY DESCRIPTION', ' SECONDARY DESCRIPTION', ' LOCATION DESCRIPTION', 'ARREST', 'DOMESTIC', 'BEAT', 'WARD', 'FBI CD', 'X COORDINATE', 'Y COORDINATE', 'LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE', 'LOCATION']

Comment: @MurtazaHaji. does `df[df.columns[0]]` work properly for you?

Comment: reloaded dataframe twice @Bharathshetty

Comment: 0         12/22/2016 02:55:00 AM
1         12/22/2016 11:17:00 AM
2         12/09/2016 12:00:00 PM
3         12/22/2016 06:50:00 PM
4         12/22/2016 07:20:00 PM
5         12/22/2016 01:00:00 AM       @MaxU

Comment: you may try to overwrite your columns: `df.columns =  ['DATE OF OCCURRENCE', 'CASE#', 'BLOCK', ' IUCR', ' PRIMARY DESCRIPTION', ' SECONDARY DESCRIPTION', ' LOCATION DESCRIPTION', 'ARREST', 'DOMESTIC', 'BEAT', 'WARD', 'FBI CD', 'X COORDINATE', 'Y COORDINATE', 'LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE', 'LOCATION']` and try it again...

Comment: Why? i tried indexing the column using case# column still getting same error @MaxU

Comment: Tried it, got the same output @MaxU

Comment: I resolved this issue there was whitespace error in the columns. Used strip command to fix the issue. Thank u for helping me out @MaxU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your column names have leading spaces.

Try this:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

Comment: Yes got  it fixed has leading whitespace stupid table

Comment: Started data analysis on python, quite a few queries coming ur way :P @MaxU

Comment: @MurtazaHaji, [good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) are always welcome ;-)

Comment: I have realised that asking good questions is important and i hope i will  be able to from now on since iv gotten better at using stackoverflow now. @MaxU